# How to detect when a user clicks on a webpage tab?

Tags: javascript, onclick, page-title

Today I discovered that youtube has this cool feature that when a video is running and you click on the tab of the webpage you can mute the video. Then when you click again, the video returns to its original volume.

I have tried my best to explain better in this image

[image: THE IMAGR]

I was excited to know the the title of a webpage could detect clicks and I tried the following code.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("foo");
});
```

Didn't work. So I tried putting a button in the title like below.

```
<title><button>test</button></title>
...
...
...
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("foo");
});
```

Didn't work. I have tried to find out through google but every post is about detecting whether the webpage is focused or not or maybe I just can't figure out the correct keywords (to google).

I really wan't to figure this out, so any help is much appreciated. I am using the latest version of Firefox (in case thats relevant).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript for handling Tab Key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316395/javascript-for-handling-tab-key-press)

Comment: I don't know this for a fact, but I would suggest that any element within the `<head>` of the page would not response to any event handling, which would therefore include `<title>`

Comment: @Don'tDownVote - that question is about the use of the Tab **key** not browser tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not something that is achievable with javascript. It's a feature implemented by recent browsers like Chrome or Firefox. For instance, in IE the mute icon is not visible. Any webpage that emit sound will have this icon.

Comment: Might be possible using something like this - [Pause html5 video when user switches tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033359/pause-html5-video-when-user-switches-tab/28033413)

Comment: So youtube itself did not do anything to make this happen?

Comment: No they didn't make anything.

Comment: let me check.. be back in a minute or two.

Comment: Checout, https://www.howtogeek.com/231959/how-to-mute-individual-browser-tabs-in-chrome-safari-and-firefox/